# selenium webdriver cant click allow when asked for microphone permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hey so i'm working on a program for telemarketers to mass call clients with ads but when my program opens the web page I get asked for microphone permissions. How can I click on allow?
[image: This is the pop up I get]

This is the code I've written so far.

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass  import getpass

username = input('Enter in your username: ')
password = getpass('Enter your password: ')
number = input('Enter number to spam: ')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.textnow.com/login')

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id('txt-username')
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id('txt-password')
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-login')
login_button.submit()

Notification_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('text linkText js-dismissButton')
Notification_button.click()

Call_button = driver.find_element_by_id('newCall')
Call_button.click()

Number_Action_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id('newCallRecipients')
Number_Action_textbox.send_keys(number)

Call_Action_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id('callButton')
Call_Action_textbox.click()
#Code works up to line 20
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for Java

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic", 1);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This is for python

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic" : 1}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: That's weird that didn't work for me. It basically didn't change anything